# Django Registration Redux Customize

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I've been trying to get a clear, simple answer to this, but I can't seem to extract anything that makes sense from either the docs or from stack overflow.

I've implemented the standard templates that come with Django Registration Redux, but I can't seem to work out how to change the form styles and the text copy that are the defaults in Redux.

Here's my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Registration Form - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="is-center pure-u-1">
                <div class="pure-u-1-2 thin-box">
                    <h1>Registration form</h1>
                    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="s-button"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

As you can see I've styled the button, but none of the elements are available for styling. The redux data must be sitting somewhere, but I've no idea where it is.

Someone on SO has suggested using crispy forms, but I'm using pureCSS rather than bootstrap, and I've already gone to the trouble of setting up a set of form styles that I want to use, so it seems like overkill to install a module with a set of styles that I then have to over-write.

Comment: Does the base.html have a appropriate style sheet?

Comment: Hi Leonard, I'm not sure what you mean. I have a style sheet with all of my custom css classes ready to call. Some of those classes are being called in the html in base.html

Comment: To me, the styling issue seems not relevent to django-registration-redux. "The redux data" is all in the `{{ form }}` and the button which does not have the style is the problem concerning purely html/css aspect to me, not concerning the module.

Comment: The redux data in the form is where the problem is. I'm successfully formatting the submit button, but the form is all aligned left rather than properly spaced and I'd like to edit the copy as well.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly you would like to access individual fields. To access them you can get the fields' names [here](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html).

So in the template instead of {{ form.as_p }} you could use individual fields like this:

for e.g. {{ form.username }}.

If you also would like to add styling then you need to use filters like:
{{ form.username | add_some_css:"my_new_class" }}. This styling needs to be configured in a separate file for e.g. redux_css.py. To make your template use this file you need to include after {% extends 'base.html' %} the following {% load redux_css %}.

Now you need to create redux_css.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def add_some_css(field, css):
    """
    Adds css to fields in Redux templates
    """
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"class":css})
```

All this should make your redux fields (which are text inputs) styled like: class="my_new_class"

Obviously you need to create .css files and "import" them into your .html files.

PS you might need to access fields errors as well, you can do this with {{ form.username.erros }}